# ASP MVC 5 Creating Treeview with check boxes on Leafnode

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, treeview

This is my model structure from which I want to use to create a treeview, with checkboxes on leaf nodes:

```
public class CategoryEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public CategoryEntity()
        : base()
    {

    }

    private Guid _categoryId;

    public Guid CategoryId
    {
        get { return _categoryId; }
        set { _categoryId = value; InvokePropertyChanged("CategoryId"); IsDirty = true; }
    }

    private string _categoryname;

    public string CategoryName
    {
        get { return _categoryname; }
        set { _categoryname = value; InvokePropertyChanged("CategoryName"); IsDirty = true; }
    }

    private string _categorydescription;

    public string CategoryDescription
    {
        get { return _categorydescription; }
        set { _categorydescription = value; InvokePropertyChanged("CategoryDescription"); IsDirty = true; }
    }

    private string _categorytype;

    public string CategoryType
    {
        get { return _categorytype; }
        set { _categorytype = value; InvokePropertyChanged("CategoryType"); IsDirty = true; }
    }

    private Guid? _parentcategoryId;

    public Guid? ParentCategoryId
    {
        get { return _parentcategoryId; }
        set { _parentcategoryId = value; InvokePropertyChanged("ParentCategoryId"); IsDirty = true; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I am new to MVC and I don't know which controls to use to display this values in a tree structure. Can anyone suggest a way of doing this?

Comment: From the model you posted, it doesn't seam like there's a tree structure. You just have a bunch of `string` and `Guid` properties. Does the `BaseEntity` declare a property with references to the same type?

Comment: consider this :https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtree/

Comment: yes Andrei V it has refernces with Same Type

Comment: @EhsanSajjad your link is broken!